# compile SCons in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, scons

I am newbie at Python and am learning to code with Python 3 (which I plan to keep as my default version). Another software, I intend to use needs Python 2 for compiling (compilation with SCons). Is there a way around this i.e. keeping Python 3 while still compiling with SCons. Can virtualenv do this?

Comment: Not informed about the current state of affairs with SCons, but generally something written for python 3.x cannot be expected to run on 2.x and vice versa. I would propose installing multiple python versions in parallel to cover the different version requirements.

Comment: Are you asking if you can install both versions on your system? Or do you want to build something with SCons which requires Python3? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

the fact that scons is python2 doesn't matter.  Your own project can be python3, python4, or anything your heart desires.  Scons doesn't care, you just need to remember that you're in python2 land *when you're editing your SConstruct files*